# Get location after moving node

Tags: javascript, gojs

How to get current location after moving node to save to database new loc.

```
myDiagram.addDigramListener("SelectionMoved",
  function(e) {
    let part = e.subject.part;
    console.log(part)
  }
)
```

But the part always is null, why?

Comment: Can you create working snippet (`[<>]` icon in editor or codepen, jsfiddle, etc.) that demonstrates your issue? Seems that `e.subject` is something different that you expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.subject` is a collection, which is the selection of **all** moved Parts. There may be more than one part moved.

If you are reasonably sure that there is only one Part moved, you can write:

```js
myDiagram.addDigramListener("SelectionMoved",
  function(e) {
    let part = e.subject.first();
    console.log(part.toString())
  }
)
```

But if you just want to save the location to the DB, why not make a two-way data binding on Location? The [flowchart example](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html) demonstrates this:

```js
// The Node.location comes from the "loc" property of the node data,
// converted by the Point.parse static method.
// If the Node.location is changed, it updates the "loc" property of the node data,
// converting back using the Point.stringify static method.
new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the following code to get new location and key

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener("SelectionMoved", function(event) {

  // https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Part.html#location
  // * PART
  var selectedNode = event.diagram.selection.first();

  console.log("selectedNode",selectedNode);
  console.log("selectedNodeKey",selectedNode.key);
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.toString());
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.x);
  console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode.location.y);
  console.log("locationObject", selectedNode.locationObject);

  //Save new location
  // key: selectedNode.key
  // location-x: selectedNode.location.x
  // location-y: selectedNode.location.y

});
```